# How to idiomatically recover from exceptions in endpoints while using EntityFramework synced collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an asp.net app. In a controller I encountered a race condition.

I started with this endpoint code:

```cs
var item = newItemInfo.ToItem();
var tagSet = ctx.Set<Tag>();

foreach (var tag in newItemInfo.Tags)
{
    var tagSameNameEntity = tagSet.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Value == tag.Value);

    if (tagSameNameEntity == null)
    {
        tagSameNameEntity = tag.ToTag();
        await tagSet.AddAsync(tagSameNameEntity);
    }

    var connection = new ItemTag
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(), TagId = tagSameNameEntity.Id, ItemId = item.Id
    };

    item.ItemTags.Add(connection);
}

await ctx.Set<Item>().AddAsync(item);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync(true);
```

Tags have a unique constraint on the name. When the endpoint is called in parallel with items that have the same tags that are also *new* I get the race condition and an exception. The requests both have a view on `tagSet` that doesn't include the new tag. Both try to add it and the second one errors.

I have tried to implement a retry loop with the help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/concurrency?redirectedfrom=MSDN). The problem is: There doesn't seem to be a mechanism analogous to `ex.Entries.Single().Reload();` for collections? At least I could find none. I can update each entity in my `tagSet` but I want to add *new missing* elements, not just update existing ones.

Through that I arrived here (note that I had the whole "get a `DbContext` in the endpoint" thing in the retry loop too, but that didn't help):

```cs
//controller field:
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

//in endpoint:

var success = await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(1000);
if (!success)
{
    return StatusCode(500);
}

previous code..

semaphoreSlim.Release();
```

This seems to work, but I now go completely against the spirit of "Optimistic concurrency" (also performance problems down the line). What would be an idiomatic way to solve this issue?

Comment: Start from loading all needed tags in one query. It will speedup performance.

Comment: Can you please clarify which framework you are using? `Asp.net` or `Asp.net core`? There are two different frameworks, you have both their tags in your question.